# All fields containing given subfield in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In MongoDB I know I can check if a subfield exist with `$exists` and dot notation, like this:

```
...{field.subfield: {$exists: 1}}...
```

but this obviously work only if I know which field to look for my subfield in.
I have documents in this format:

```
{
    field1: {
                subfield1: asd,
                subfield2: asd
            },
    field2: {
                subfield2: asd,
                subfield3: asd
            },
    field3: {
                subfield1: asd,
                subfield3: asd,
            }
}
```

In this example, say that my subfield of interest is subfield2, I want to project (or match, or whatever, I'm looking for a general answer) only field1 and field2, excluding field3 (that doesn't contain subfield2).

My documents could contain tens or hundreds of fields, so manually checking one by one isn't viable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "root": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$root"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "root.v.subfield2": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "root": {
        "$addToSet": "$root"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "root": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$root"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "field1": "$root.field1",
      "field2": "$root.field2",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SA7ZrofTMN8)